# pgfplots: Hide curves from plot

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a way to hide the first two curves, so only the Total is shown?

Unfortunately, `forget plot` only excludes a curve from being listed in the legend.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\RequirePackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stack plots=y,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    minor x tick num=1,
    minor y tick num=1,
    ymin=0,
    grid=both,
    ] 
        \addplot [forget plot, line width=0pt] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};  % HIDE from graph but use for Total
        \addplot [forget plot, line width=0pt] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};  % HIDE from graph but use for Total
        \addplot [line width=2pt, mark=*] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)}; 

        \legend{Total}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Like to hide two curves to only show the Total]

Even with `line width=0pt`, those lines are still visible...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `draw=none`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\RequirePackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[stack plots=y,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    minor x tick num=1,
    minor y tick num=1,
    ymin=0,
    grid=both,
    ] 
        \addplot [forget plot, draw=none] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};  % HIDE from graph but use for Total
        \addplot [forget plot, draw=none] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};  % HIDE from graph but use for Total
        \addplot [line width=2pt, mark=*] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)}; 

        \legend{Total}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yay! Thanks!!
That was too easy :-)